# What piece of the last update could break keyboard switcher, systray, clipboard and Adobe Flash in Xubuntu 11.04?

Tags: 11.04, xubuntu, xfce

I was succesfully using Xubuntu 11.04 for some days, but after today update (I haven't updated during the last 2 days) lots of things stopped working: Adobe Flash Firefox plugin, clipboard, notification area panel applet, keyboard layout switcher panel applet, sound volume panel applet, cpu meter panel applet.

Lack of clipboard really annoys.

What could be the reason? Is there a a way to fix this?

Comment: You mentioned 11.04 on the title, and 10.04 on the description, could you please clarify ? Thanks

Comment: 11.04 actually.

Comment: hm, If you have not updated in two days, there are many updates that could have caused issues. When running the development release, it is important to update at least daily.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as too localized, when running the developmental release too many things can break too often and there's a lot of churn; things like this are best reported as bugs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There have been [some problems with GTK](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gtk+2.0/+bug/693758) in 11.04 - your problems could well be related.

*Sidenote: I would encourage you to take most discussion of/problems with development releases to the [Natty part of the Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/forumdisplay.php?f=394).*